# Google search engine: How to search for pattern

Tags: search-engine, google-search

I was wondering if it is possible to search a pattern(more like regular expression pattern).

E.g in python the regular expressions `/[f[a-z]{2}d]/` would return words like 'Food'. I want to do the same using google search engine.

My question "Is it possible to achieve this?".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a search engine that support regular expression search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119065/is-there-a-search-engine-that-support-regular-expression-search)

Answer (score 1):

No, Google does not currently allow a partial word search. I had repeatedly found this needed when I search say Youtube or Gmail.